# Simultaneously write and read a file from NDK in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-file

I am writing into a file using android-ndk . So writing in file is taking place using native c code.

It contains some kind of readings that i am putting in using ndk.
On click of a button the writing into a file start. And simultaneously i want to read contents of file and use them into another thread for showing up the values as writing operation might continue for 15 sec and user will have to wait for that much time to see the result so i want to show result one by one as soon as i get it into that file.

Is it feasible ,if yes can show me the way how to go about that?

Well i started with it and right nw its how i am doing it ,,

```
Thread thr1 = new Thread(r1);
Thread thr2 = new Thread(r2);
thr1.start();
thr2.start();



r1 = new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            File sdcard= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            nativeFunction(sdcard +"/readings.txt");
            //takingReading=false;
            readingFile = new File(sdcard +"/readings.txt");

            Log.i("length of file", ""+readingFile.length());
          }
        };




r2 = new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            try {

                  Thread.sleep(3000);
                  File sdcard= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

                readingFile = new File(sdcard +"/readings.txt");

                Log.i("length of file", ""+readingFile.length());


            } catch (InterruptedException iex) {}
          }
        };
```

nativeFunction opens

```
file= fopen(location,"w+");
```

This function keeps on writing things in file for around 2 minutes,
but i need to continuously get the values entered bye native function so i started 2nd thread but when i check file.length() its always 0.

and when nativefunction write is complete then actual file size comes. So how to get around this problem?

Comment: i wanted to kw the feasibility , whether it is possible or not,, then only i was thinking of starting that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible using pthreads. So you need to spawn 2 threads, one doing the writing and other doing the reading. If you are doing it from the same file, you may run into race conditions, so be careful.

More more info on pthreads, kindly google. It's commonly used by the Linux world.

Comment: thnks for giving a goahead on this , thnks a lot

Comment: You can spawn a reader thread from Java and call into NDK from that. It's marginally easier.

Comment: i have added more details and where i m stuck nw,,

Comment: Probably mixing up Java threads with NDK might not be a good idea. Why dont you impplement both with NDK?

Comment: the String that i am storing is smthng like 23,34,45,32,12,45 and so on,,,that is the work that NDK is doing.
Now i want to read those values and change the values accordingly in edittext that is present Java.

Comment: you are trying to read a file while its simultaneously being written?? If that is so, then its a race condition isnt it? in such cases the results might be unpredictable..read from a seperate file and write to a seperate file.

Comment: how can that be achieved in here? Means if i write to another file that the file that i need to read,Reading other file wont provide the solution of the problem that i have ?

Comment: Amit, the very concept of readers writers problem is to prevent a read/write to a same file simultaneously. Because it will give you unpredictable results. Lots of things like timing issues, read after write, write after reads will crop up and these are impossible to solve. Architectues have been remodelled to solve these. So, you will want to write then read your file seperately if its a single file.