# reading multiple files/catalogs simultaneously (manifest)

Tags: android, multithreading

My ultimate goal is to make files' **manifest**. From wiki: *A manifest file in computing is a file containing metadata for a group of accompanying files that are part of a set or coherent unit. For example, the files of a computer program may have a manifest describing the name, version number, license and the constituting files of the program.*

The first task I have to handle is to read files' paths **as fast as** it possible. At the moment Im reading files like this:

```
 PackageManager  pm = activity.getPackageManager();
 List<PackageInfo> packgeList = pm.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
 List<ApplicationInfo> applicationsList = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
        try {
            for (int x=0; x < packgeList.size(); x++){
                if(applicationsList.get(x).publicSourceDir.startsWith("/data/")){
                    dictionary.put(applicationsList.get(x).publicSourceDir);
                }

            }
        }
```

But this runs quiet slow. **Because at the one time it can run/scan only** `"\data\"` folder in this case.

I need your advice - should I use threads/tasks and create N different threads running on phone for every catalog scanning like in this example:

[Simultaneously write and read a file from NDK in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856215/simultaneously-write-and-read-a-file-from-ndk-in-android)

---

Related:

http://www.androprogrammer.com/2013/12/simultaneously-read-and-write-in-file.html

Comment: [Another solution maybe ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29340527/8664869)

Comment: What is "runs slow" exactly? What measurements have you made? What part exactly is slowing down the process?

Comment: The amount of files , that is what slows me down. I didnt measure it, however, 10 sec delay on getting just list of files sounds kind of a long term, or am I wrong ?

Comment: You mean `getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)` takes 10 seconds?

Comment: That is correct.